# How to locate the element using xpath through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

How to locate the element using xpath through Selenium

Code trial:

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-2') and contains(text(), \"Men's Downshifter 9 Training Shoes\")]"));
```

HTML:

```html
<h2 class="a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-2">
    <a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/Nike-Downshifter-Running-Shoes-Anthracite/dp/B07H84PMGS/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&amp;keywords=NIKE+TRAINERS+FOR+MEN&amp;qid=1578766779&amp;sr=8-3">
    
<span class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal">Men's Downshifter 9 Training Shoes</span>
            
       </a>

    
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Closure `]`

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-2') and contains(text(), \"Men's Downshifter 9 Training Shoes\")]]"));
```

Alternatives:

1. `//h2[.='Men's Downshifter 9 Training Shoes']`
2. `//span[.='Men's Downshifter 9 Training Shoes']/ancestor::h2[1]`
3. `//h2[./a[.='Men's Downshifter 9 Training Shoes']]`

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `text()`:

  ```
  By.xpath("//span[text()=\"Men's Downshifter 9 Training Shoes\"]"));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  By.xpath("//span[@class='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal' and contains(., 's Downshifter 9 Training Shoes')]"));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and parent `<a>` tag:

  ```
  By.xpath("//a[@class='a-link-normal a-text-normal' and starts-with(@href, '/Nike-Downshifter-Running-Shoes-Anthracite/dp/')]/span[@class='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal' and contains(., 'Downshifter 9 Training Shoes')]"));
  ```